# Identifying the market of a stock

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges

I am completely new to stocks, but i want to try to buy stock from another market - other than my country.

So how can i figure out data for a particular stock?

Even the most basic, how can i find, for a particular stock, in which stock exchange does it belong to?

Answer (score 2):

As a small investor, I don't worry about what exchange a particular stock is on.

I created an account with an online broker -- TD Ameritrade in my case, but there are many others out there, and I can't recommend one over another. Then if I'm interested in a stock, I look it up on their website. If they list it, than I can buy it. There are probably stocks in the world not listed on TD Ameritrade. I've had times when I've thought about investing in a particular company and couldn't find it. Maybe that means they're not a public company, maybe I don't have the formal name or they're really owned by a holding company or some such, or maybe they're just not on an exchange that my broker deals with. In any case, I don't worry about it.

If I do find the stock on the broker's web site, than they give me a fair amount of information about it: the latest price of course, what the price has been for the past several years, the last dividend if any, ratings by several well known investment advisory companies, etc. If I want to know more I usually just google the company name and see what else I can find out about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the country that you want to buy the stock, you can Google it.

For example: "NFLX Germany Stock Exchange".

The stock may trade on more than one than one exchange in that country so if you have a preference, pick one.

Answer (score 0):

Your broker will let you sort and filter stocks by exchange.